# spring setter injection call confusion

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

Below is the code snippet from Spring Reference documentation on Spring-JDBC

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

```
public class JdbcDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        System.out.println("inside the setDatasource");
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
```

XML configuration file entry is::

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

   
   <bean id="jdbcDao" class="learning.spring.dao.JdbcDao">
        <property name="**dataSource**" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

My question is How the Setter injection happening here even though JdbcDao class does not have any property with name dataSource. So if a property is not there in the bean then how come the setter has been called?

Answer (score 0):

it's because the injection is done by setter method, not by field names, and setter method name assumed by the property name matched the actual setter method name in `JdbcDao` class.

try reading these articles.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-xml-injection

https://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring